# how to open an HTML page on a button click from a Java Swing app?

Tags: java, html, swing

I have a GUI  form using Java Swing. I have also designed an HTML page. Now what i want is, on a button click I want to open that HTML page.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so in my actionPerformed method i just need to write Desktop.open(abc.html) ?

Comment: Yes you can use explore other methods also of `Desktop` class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Desktop#browse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29).

Look at other method also

[Desktop#open()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

Explore other method also.

Answer (score 0):

use `Dektop.open(File);`

where File should be your html file with correct path.

```
    file should be in desktop.
```

use like below

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/karibasappagc/Desktop/temp1.txt");
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i used Desktop.open("d:\em\ems\abc.html") , i got 3 errors: illegal escape character

Comment: @user3367768 use escape character `d:\\em\\ems\\abc.html` or use forward slash `/`.

Comment: use / instead of \, like d:/em/ems/abc.html

Comment: i used Desktop.open(d:/Em/Ems/ga.html); i got 5 errors: illegal start of expression , not a statement , ; expected

Comment: when i used Desktop.open("d:/Em/Ems/ga.html"); i got required: File found: String

Comment: Used your code.but now on button click i'm getting a stackTrace that says the File :  "d:/em/ems/ga.html" does not exist.But the file exists in the path specified.

Comment: got it,sorry just saw file name,it was "ga.html.html" :p
Thanks

Comment: okie..fine..no prob..